# Which is better for good UI Experience (Html Pages or data-role='page')

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile application using Jquery mobile framwork & phonegap. So, I was wondering whether to use different html pages for my application or different  to make the transitions smoother and to provide better UI experience.

Comment: Maybe a question better suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: [This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: Just rewrite the question a bit then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that if you include your whole application in one html file that your [dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) size could easily get unreasonably large. To quote the documentation

> Usually, it's a good idea to store your app's pages in several
>   single-page templates instead of one large multi-page template. This
>   minimizes the size of the page's DOM.

Also the next paragraph may help you.

> When using single-page templates, you can prefetch pages into the DOM
>   so that they're available instantly when the user visits them. To
>   prefetch a page, add the data-prefetch attribute to a link that points
>   to the page. jQuery Mobile then loads the target page in the
>   background after the primary page has loaded and the pagecreate event
>   has triggered. For example:

```
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

> You can prefetch as many linked pages as you like. Just add data-prefetch to all the links you want to prefetch.

Answer (score 0):

The best is working with [OpenGl](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) of curse, then [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), then html